# PyInstaller ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, pandas, compilation, pyinstaller

I've been grappling with PyInstaller and not sure how to fix ModuleNotFound (specifically `pandas`). My .py program is a simple onefile script that imports only (Anaconda-)native packages (eg tkinter, pandas, os) and it worked in the IDE. I know that PyInstaller only import top-level packages so I'll list my approaches so far:

1. Run in virtual env to downgrade Python 3.8 to 3.7.5. I heard people had problem with PyInstaller with Python 3.8. Also updated latest version of PyInstaller. Also tried without env.
2. Build from onedir instead of onefile `pyinstaller --onedir myscript.py`
3. Change `hiddenimports` in spec file to `hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas', etc.]` and also `hiddenimports = ['pandas']`
4. Put `import pandas` at the top in .py
5. Follow this one: [How can I add a Python site-package folder (that's not being included) to a PyInstaller spec file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743234/how-can-i-add-a-python-site-package-folder-thats-not-being-included-to-a-pyin) but fix my path file to `C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda\\lib` since this was in Anaconda interpreter. Then it raised `AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'` and I tried to fixed it to no avail

None of that has worked out. Is there a better way to go about building executable in Python or is there a fix for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas

Comment: @VikramadityaGaonkar Interesting, now it raises ``ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: No module named 'numpy'`` without me ever importing numpy in my script. I had numpy installed in both Anaconda and Python lib. Not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by reinstalling pandas and numpy. I didn't think of this because I reinstalled pandas during the process multiple times. Anyway if anyone was having the same problem and need a last resort:

`pip uninstall pandas -y
pip uninstall numpy -y
pip install pandas
pip install numpy`

Edit:
After this I realize that the way I installed/hooked up Anaconda was messy so I reinstalled Anaconda and pyinstaller was so much easier to work with. To use pyinstaller with Anaconda instead of default python after reinstalling Anaconda, `conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller`